# Logic question on inequalities

Tags: inequality, logic, optimization

Suppose I have some functions $f_1(x), f_2(x), f_3(x)$ that map elements $x$ from some finite set $\mathcal{X}$ to nonnegative real numbers. It is known that $f_3(x) \geq f_1(x)$ and $f_3(x)\geq f_2(x)$ for any $x$. For any $x\in\mathcal{X}$, let $c_1, c_2$ be constants such that
$$\begin{align}
c_1 &\geq f_1(x) \\
c_2 &\geq f_2(x) \\
c_1 + c_2 &\geq f_3(x) 
\end{align}$$

Does it then follow that
$$\begin{align}
c_1 &\geq \max_{x}f_1(x) \\
c_2 &\geq \max_{x}f_2(x) \\
c_1 + c_2 &\geq \max_{x}f_3(x) 
\end{align}$$

If yes, then these are two equivalent ways of expressing the set of all $(c_1, c_2)$ that satisfy the inequalities.

Comment: Is it "for any $x$, there are constants $c_1, c_2$ satisfying inequalities ... " or "there are constants $c_1, c_2$ satisfying the inequalities for any $x$ ...."? In the latter case you can certainly proceed in the way you want

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally,
$$c \ge g(x) \ \forall x \iff c \ge \max_x g(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let be $X:= \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$ a finite set in which $f(x) \leq c \in \mathbb{R},   \forall x \in X$ then for some $x_i \in X$:
\begin{equation}
c \geq f(x_i) = \max_x f(x) \Rightarrow c \geq \max_x f(x)
\end{equation}
Is that your doubt?